# How to check folder size in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

You can look up file sizes on Google drive but it does not show the size of the whole folder.

I've been looking for ways to get the size of a folder on Google Drive but couldn't find any.

Is there any way to see how much space a folder has taken on Google Drive?